# Volume Absorption not working

Tags: modeling, materials, color, volumetrics

[image: the node setup]

I am making a cup of coffee. I created the liquid as a mesh with transmission as 0 and applied volume absorption to the mesh in order to create that darker look, however, there is no change in the appearance of the liquid after applying the volume absorption.

I cannot figure out why the absorption is not applying. I have set the density to 584 so that can't be the issue. So why does the appearance of the liquid not change?

Comment: A picture of your liquid, and of your node setup, might help.

Comment: Don't use the Principled BSDF shader on the surface, use glass, but if you Must use the principled shader increase the transmission to 1 so that the material is not opaque.

Comment: Add the render-engine as a tag please.

Comment: It looks like you have the material with the *Volume Absorption* in the second material slot. Is the material actually applied to your object or is only the material from the first slots assigned to the faces? If you have assigned the correct material, have you checked that the mesh is watertight (doesn't have holes)?

Comment: You may want to use volume scatter instead of volume absorption.

Comment: Changing the feature set to experimental worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

*[user1853's comment in pictures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162700/volume-absorption-not-working#comment275291_162700) :)*

---

Change **Transmission** to 1
[image]

... or use *Glass* shader instead of *Principled BSDF.*
[image]

*The only weird thing is when I replicate your node, result is totally white, not transparent as yours ... hm. Some changes happened from 2.81?*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by going into *Edit mode*, select all faces, click on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>  and choose *Flip*.

Turns out normals were flipped and messing up the volume

Answer (score 1):

[image: blender screenshot]

I too faced similar issue. I solved it by selecting "Disconnect" under "Volume" to unselect the "Volume Absorption" and then reselected it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue turned out that in in **Material Properties** there was another texture besides "coffee". When I deleted it was coloured into coffee one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same tutorial and ran into the same issue. When I hit tab to go into edit mode it fixed the density for some reason.

Comment: Please delete your post. You are in answer section. Instead create a new question if answers or comments here did not helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Disconnecting** and **connecting** the volume node in the **shader** tab did it.
Took me a lot of time figuring that out.
*Maybe a glitch in the 2.91 version..*

Answer (score 0):

I did the same tutorial and had also that problem. I had to increase density ridiculously, like 10000, to see an effect. I guess it's a matter of scale. If your coffee cup is a few cm wide, the light rays have a very short journey to get absorbed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found it in the comments under the tutorial.

And here it is:
[image]